# What plane would an aboleth be from for the purposes of Banishment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, planes

An aboleth is classified as a large aberration. If someone were to use the Banishment spell, what plane would it be banished to? (if it is from a different plane?)
Or would it just be banished to the 'harmless demiplane'?

Answer (score 16):

#### It depends on which plane is native for the aboleth.

Aberrations can be from different planes, including the Material Plane, Far realms, or other odd spaces.  According to their *Monster Manual* entry, aboleths can be native to a variety of planes.

> Aboleths dwell in watery environments, including ocean abysses, deep lakes, and the Elemental Plane of Water.

Some aboleths may be reincarnations of past aboleths, and their bodies are native to the Elemental Plane of Water.

> If an aboleth's body is destroyed, its spirit returns to the Elemental Plane of Water, where a new body coalesces for it over days or months.

So a particular aboleth may be from the natural oceans of the Material Plane, in which case the [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) spell would temporarily send it to a harmless demiplane.

> If the target is native to the plane of existence you're on, you banish the target to a harmless demiplane.

Another aboleth may be native to some alien depths in the Elemental Plane of Water, in which case *banishment* would instead send them back home.

> If the target is native to a different plane of existence than the one you're on, the target is banished with a faint popping noise, returning to its home plane.

Comment: And listening for the _faint popping noise_ tells you where it went, and whether it's coming back after 1 minute!